# Net::SMTP module sometimes returns an empty string

Tags: perl, email

I am sending mail from address to mail function of `Net::SMTP module`, but the mail function returns empty string some times instead of Undef(error):

```
$feeder->mail( $mailfrom );->This line invoking mail function of Net::SMTP 
                          module

      sub mail {-> this subroutine belongs to Net::SMTP module
                my $me   = shift;
                my $addr = _addr($me, shift);
                my $opts = "";

                if (@_) {
                        }
                $me->_MAIL("FROM:" . $addr . $opts);
              }
 sub _MAIL { shift->command("MAIL", @_)->response() == CMD_OK }-> Here _MAIL 
                             function invoking command function of Net::Cmd
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @PerlDuck I am sending mailfrom address to mail function of Net::SMTP module, but the mail function returns empty sring some times Instead of Undef(error).

Comment: @saikanthatluri That's not a question.